# Conditional probability for throwing tail when head already appeared

Tags: probability

> You throw a coin until tail appears for the first time. You know that head appeared when you threw the coin the first time, so let $n > 1$. Calculate the Conditional probability for throwing number the $n$-th time.

We know that the probability for throwing either tail or head is $1 \over 2$. My first intuition told me that throwing head first doesn't make a difference, but I am not sure about that.

For example, when we take a look at $n = 2$, there are only two possible outcomes, namely $\{H, H\}$ and $\{H, T\}$. Now, in general, when we ask "How high is the probability to throw $H$ two times in a row?", it is obviously $1 \over 4$. It is the same for "How high is the probability to throw$ H$ first and $T$ second?" This leads to the question "How high is the probability to throw $H$ when $H$ was already thrown in the first round?" The answer must be $1 \over 2$, and it is, again, the same for $\{H, T\}$.

Now we didn't make a statement about the throws for $n > 1$, which means that the task can be formulated as: "How high is the probability to throw $T$ in the $n$-th round when $H$ was thrown in the first round?" Well, it must be $1 \over 2 $ again. So, basically, it doesn't make a difference whether we threw $H$ in the first round or not, the probability for throwing $T$ in the $n$-th round is always $1 \over 2 $ when we don't make any other assumptions.

But that makes me wonder: Isn't it a whole different story for a question like: "How high is the probability for throwing $T$ in the $n$-th round when $H$ was thrown in every single round before?" The answer must be $1$ $-$ $1 \over 2^{n-1}$, right? So, actually, it *does* make a difference somehow to throw $H$ first, but one doesn't notice because $1 -$ $1 \over 2^{n}$ $=$ $1 \over 2$ for $n = 1.$

Plus, how would I formalize that? When $E = \{H, T\}$ and $F = \{H\}$, and I know that $F$ already happened, does that mean that $P(F) = 1$? Plus, the problem with the definition is that $P(E \cap F) =$ $\{H\}$ which actually should be $1 \over 2$, but I already noted that it would be $1$, so that doesn't make sense.

**Edit:**

So it was mentioned that the probability is the same for every flip. But I still don't see how to formalize it. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please explain "You throw a coin until number appears for the first time"? I've got a few coins in my pocket, with several numbers on both sides.

Comment: Possible meaning: Find the conditional probability that the first head occurs on trial $n>1$ given that the first trial was a head.

Comment: Or is there a problem with my definition of a coin? :D In Europe, a coin has two sides with one being a picture of a famous person or something like that while the other side has printed the value of the coin on it. In German, we say "Kopf oder Zahl", I would translate it as "Head or Number", but maybe this has a slightly different meaning in English?

Comment: "Find the conditional probability that the first number occurs on trial $n>1$ given that the first trial was a head." is correct.

Comment: Typically denoted *Heads or Tails* (use $H$ for Heads and $T$ for Tails).

Comment: Corrected it in your favor. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The odds of getting T on a fair coin is always 1/2, no matter what you got on previous flips. They're independent events, there's no way for the outcome of one flip to affect the outcome of another.

What you need to find is the probability of T given that you got H on the first flip, not the probability of H and then T. The latter here is 1/4, since you're looking at the full sequence of two flips. However, you know you already got H on the first flip, so that event is a given.

Comment: So even if I would flip head $n$ times in a row, then the probability for throwing tail in the round $(n+1)$ would still be $1 \over 2$?

Comment: Yes. Suppose I hand you a coin and ask you to flip it, you would expect a 50-50 chance of tails. Now suppose I hand you the same coin, but tell you that I flipped it and got heads 10 times in a row. That information will have no effect whatsoever on how you flip the coin and what the outcome is. Every flip is independent of any flip in the past.

Comment: Okay then, makes sense. But still, how do I formalize it? What sets do I need here? And how high is the probability of the flip that already happened? 1?